# Scala shapeless typing Map[Symbol, String] with case classes

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm reading in query parameters and converting them into a `Map[Symbol, String]`. I would like to add some type safety to these query parameters through a set of case classes.

These case classes will be different depending on the incoming http request, so this needs to support different case classes.

If the incoming query parameters don't match the defined `case class` the `Parser` should return `None`.

I have attempted to use shapeless to implement a generic parser. It work's if all of the parameters are of type `String`. But I need to support any type of query parameter.

I've tried to incorporate the implicit conversion logic seen in this post, but unable to get it working.
https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2015/11/08/type-classes-and-generic-derivation/ (new to shapeless)

Existing `Parser` (without string to type conversion):

```scala
class Parser[A] {
  def from[R <: HList]
  (m: Map[Symbol, String])
  (implicit
   gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, R],
   fromMap: FromMap[R]
  ): Option[A] = fromMap(m).map(gen.from)
}

object Parser {
  def to[A]: Parser[A] = new Parser[A]
}
```

Tests describing issue:

```scala
class ParserSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  private val sampleName: String = "Bob"
  private val sampleVersion: Int = 1

  //Partial Solution
  case class QueryParams(name: String, version: String)

  //Full Solution (not working)
  case class QueryParams2(name: String, version: Int)

  "A Parser" should "parse query parameters from a map with only string values" in {
    val mapOfQueryParams = Map('name -> sampleName, 'version -> sampleVersion.toString)
    val result = Parser.to[QueryParams].from(mapOfQueryParams)

    result shouldBe 'defined
    result.get.name shouldEqual sampleName
    result.get.version shouldEqual sampleVersion.toString
  }
  it should "parse query parameters from a map with any type of value" in {
    val mapOfQueryParams = Map('name -> sampleName, 'version -> sampleVersion.toString)
    val result = Parser.to[QueryParams2].from(mapOfQueryParams)

    //result is not defined as it's not able to convert a string to integer
    result shouldBe 'defined
    result.get.name shouldEqual sampleName
    result.get.version shouldEqual sampleVersion
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FromMap` uses `shapeless.Typeable` to convert values to the expected type. So the easiest way to make your code work is to define an instance of `Typeable` to convert from `String` to `Int` (and additional `Typeable` instances for any value type, that appears in your case classes):

```
implicit val stringToInt: Typeable[Int] = new Typeable[Int] {
  override def cast(t: Any): Option[Int] = t match {
    case t: String => Try(t.toInt).toOption
    case _ => Typeable.intTypeable.cast(t)
  }

  override def describe: String = "Int from String"
}
```

This is however not an intended use of `Typeable`, which is designed to confirm that a variable with type `Any` is already an instance of the expected type without any conversion. In other words it's intended to be a typesafe implementation of `asInstanceOf`, that can also work around type erasure.

---

For correctness you can define your own `ReadFromMap` typeclass, that uses your own `Read` typeclass for conversion from `String`s to the expected types. Here is a simple implementation of the `Read` typeclass (assuming Scala 2.12):

```
import scala.util.Try

trait Read[T] {
  def apply(string: String): Option[T]
}

object Read {
  implicit val readString: Read[String] = Some(_)
  implicit val readInt: Read[Int] = s => Try(s.toInt).toOption
  // Add more implicits for other types in your case classes
}
```

And you can copy and adapt the implementation of `FromMap` to use this `Read` typeclass:

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.labelled._

trait ReadFromMap[R <: HList] extends Serializable {
  def apply(map: Map[Symbol, String]): Option[R]
}

object ReadFromMap {
  implicit def hnil: ReadFromMap[HNil] = _ => Some(HNil)

  implicit def hlist[K <: Symbol, V, T <: HList](implicit
    keyWitness: Witness.Aux[K],
    readValue: Read[V],
    readRest: ReadFromMap[T]
  ): ReadFromMap[FieldType[K, V] :: T] = map => for {
    value <- map.get(keyWitness.value)
    converted <- readValue(value)
    rest <- readRest(map)
  } yield field[K](converted) :: rest
}
```

Then simply use this new typeclass in your `Parser`:

```
class Parser[A] {
  def from[R <: HList]
  (m: Map[Symbol, String])
  (implicit
    gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, R],
    fromMap: ReadFromMap[R]
  ): Option[A] = fromMap(m).map(gen.from)
}
```